# EditText value duplicate in child ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, expandablelistview

When i write something in the EditText and open other group/ExpandableListView, random child EditText is with the same value i write on the first one, blank or 0, but the 0 know i'ts from the onFocusChange. I want all of them to start with 0 and don't duplicate when i write something in the EditText, if anyone could help me I would be grateful.

Here's my getChildView of the Adapter

Adapter

```
@Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.questions_itens, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.EditNumber);

                holder.editText.setText(editModelArrayList.get(childPosition).getEditTextValue());
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                 holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }


             final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
            holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus)
                    {
                        if (!finalHolder.editText.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        {
                            editModelArrayList.get(childPosition).setEditTextValue("0");
                        }else {
                            editModelArrayList.get(childPosition).setEditTextValue("");
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

            holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    editModelArrayList.get(childPosition).setEditTextValue(holder.editText.getText().toString());



                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });


            TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Item);


            Question question = (Question) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            item.setText(question.getNome());

            return convertView;
        }

       private class ViewHolder {

            protected EditText editText;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fix this bug, but i know it's because when i set the EditText i only using the child position, so all other child's with the same position will get the same value, so i used two switch's one to check group position e other to child position. I don't know if there's a better way to do that, since i new to expandable and other things, but it worked for me.

i used the Switch's like this

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

          switch (groupPosition)
                    {

                        case 0:
                            switch (childPosition)
                            {
                                case 0:                                       
                                    break;

                                case 1:

                                    break;

                                case 2:
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            switch (childPosition)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    break;

                                case 1:
                                    break;

                                case 2:
                                    break;

                                case 3:
                                    break;

                            }
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            switch (childPosition)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    break;

                                case 1:
                                    break;

                                case 2:

                                    break;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            switch (childPosition)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    break;

                            }
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            switch (childPosition)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    break;

                                case 1:
                                    break;

                            }
                            break;
                    }
}
```